# Can't add Google Map to Navigation Drawer fragment

Tags: android, google-maps, navigation-drawer

I'm trying to make an app in Android and I want to add a Map in a Navigation Drawer. The drawer options open new fragments but can't make the Map fragment to work.

The **MainActivity.java** sets the fragment the following way:

```
/**
 * Diplaying fragment view for selected nav drawer list item
 * */
private void displayView(int position) {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    Fragment fragment = null;
    switch (position) {
    case 0:
        fragment = new HomeFragment();
        break;
    case 1:
        fragment = new PoliFragment();
        break;
    case 2:
        fragment = new TilefonaFragment();
        break;
    case 3:
        fragment = new DromologiaFragment();
        break;
    case 4:
        fragment = new XartisFragment();
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }

    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();

        // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
        //setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
    } else {
        // error in creating fragment
        Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
    }
}
```

The map fragment (**XartisFragment.java**) is the following:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;


public class XartisFragment extends Fragment {
private GoogleMap map;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.map_layout,container, false);

    map =   ((SupportMapFragment) getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();//((SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
    return rootView;
}


}
```

The **map_layout.xml** is the following:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

When I try to run it I get:

```
Error:(178, 15) error: incompatible types: XartisFragment cannot be converted to Fragment
```

It points the error to this line in MainActivity.java

```
fragment = new XartisFragment();
```

Any ideas about what to change in order to make it load?

Comment: import android.support.v4.app.Fragment; in where displayView() method class

Comment: fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit(); error throws from here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `getSupportFragmentManager()` instead `getFragmentManager()`.

or

Make sure that both places are importing the same Fragment class. It feels a bit like in one place you are importing android.app.Fragment (the native API Level 11 version of fragments) and in the other places you are importing android.support.v4.app.Fragment (the fragments from the Android Support package).

Comment: Thanx a lot @Duggu . That seemed to be the problem, Change everything to android.app.Fragment (since i don't want to support older devices) and removed everything that mentioned Support classes and now it loads properly.